# can i project to a different type conditionally?

Tags: linq-to-sql, inheritance, projection

If i have a `Car`, `Bus` and `UnknownVehicle` that derive from `Vehicle` then based on a "Type" field in my database, can i project into a different type based on a condition?

Like this:

```
public IQueryable<Vehicle> GetAllVehicles()
{
    return from vehicle in dc.Vehicles
    select vehicle.Type == "C" ? new Car(vehicle.ID) : vehicle.Type == "B" ? new Bus(vehicle.ID) : new UnknownVehicle(vehicle.ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static FactoryMethod (it's a pattern) on Vehicle which will return the object of a class you need.

Something like that:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    ...
    public static Vehicle GetVehicle( VehicleType type, int id )
    {
        switch( type )
        {
            case 'C':
                return( new Car( id ) );
            case 'B':
                return( new Bus( id ) );
            default:
                return( new UnknownVehicle( id ) );

        }
    }
}
```

And use it in code like that

```
public IQueryable<Vehicle> GetAllVehicles()
{
    return( from vehicle in dc.Vehicles
        select Vehicle.GetVehicle( vehicle.Type, vehicle.ID ) );
}
```

Though for the switch to work, your Type should be char, not string. But you use one-letter types anyway.

Comment: thanks for the response. yeh i had something like this before the inline conditional. but that [switch statement] wont translate to SQL (L2S exception)

Comment: Well, as long as you are using Linq2Sql as the ORM, I don't think you can manage what you want directly. L2S needs a mapping of entities to tables.

Comment: You can use Vehicle as a container class, and Car/Bus/UnknownVehicle as a contained class/Strategy to handle different behaviour between differing types of Vehicles.

Comment: @Kaerber What do you mean by having the Car/Bus/UnknownVehicle as a contained class? Do you mean like having a property on the `Vehicle` type which evaluates to `Car`/`Bus`/`UnknownVehicle`?

Comment: You can put all the type-specific behavior into the separate class, CarStrategy/BusStrategy/UnknownVehicleStrategy, based on say abstract VehicleStrategy, and route all the relevant calls to methods to the Strategy class. This way, though you would have a only a Vehicle class in your collection, each instance will behave according to its real type (Bus, Car, etc).

Comment: This way I think you'll keep your linq-to-sql happy, and behavior of your Vehicle objects in line with your expectations.

Comment: I see your point (i think) but i'm reluctant to decouple the data from the behaviour by more or less having a collection of DTOs and then the strategy classes for behaviour. My DDD brain is not linking that. :(
Any thoughts?